# Family records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure. One of the missing component is the 'Family column' in my table.

I want to family all the child programs along with the Parent program. So Child programs CP_1 to CP_5 belong to Parent PP_1. So they should all be familiarized as '1'. Similarly the next set CP_1 belong to second set of PP_1 and they should be familiarized as '2'. Any help?!

Desired output:

[image]

Rextester: https://rextester.com/UCNJ96841

Comment: Your question is simply unclear, what is the conditions here? How to know that child belongs to a parent? and which one of the two images are the desired results?

Comment: @Sami . . . The two images were the same.  The downvotes seem unfriendly, especially given that the OP included a rextester example.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, I ask for clarification, and that doesn't mean that I DV the question, BTW DV is not something we can control and the question miss things needed.

Comment: @Sami . . . The comment gives the OP the opportunity to respond.  Personally I don't downvote.  But if I did, I would want to give people an opportunity to fix things.  I found the question to be clear and appreciated the rextester example.

Comment: People, I don't see 2 images but sorry if you guys do. But yes, I want to add the 'Family' column to my existing table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just use a cumulative sum on the number of times that `CCODE` is `'NULL'`:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when ccode = 'NULL' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by cid order by eid) as family_num
from #test t;
```

Note that `'NULL'` is a highly unusual string value.  You seem to know the difference between `'NULL'` and `NULL`, but I think the latter might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks  Gordon. Technically, the row PP_1 with null in CP column is the Parent program. So I have to family all the CP rows with this PP_1 parent row